# Routing between Angular & Laravel

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-routing, angular-routing

I am trying to make a simple App in Angular , integration with Laravel 5 and facing issues while routing the application views.

`Routes.php` looks like as below:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});
```

in Routes.php, i am handling only first time when application loads.

> But after that i want to handle all routing by Angular. So, i did like this:

`app.js` file

```
var membershipModule = angular.module('membershipModule', ['ngMaterial','ngRoute']);

membershipModule.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $mdThemingProvider){

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette().accentPalette('blue-grey');

    $routeProvider
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'LoginController',
            templateUrl: 'views/login.html'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            controller: 'RegisterController',
            templateUrl: 'views/register.html'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: "/"});
        $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
});
```

But when i access `http://localhost:8000/#/login` then it throws error that `views/login.html` is not found.

- I tried making `login.html` in Laravel Default Folder as below screen

[image]

- Also Tried making `views/login.html` in root dir as below

[image]

**but none of it is working**

Comment: One question: why are you using PHP framework when you wish to use static HTML templates? And `resources/views` is not Laravel default frontend directory. That would be `public`.

Comment: @Gags, It is difficult to manage, batter than you can make api's in laravel and develop front end in separate angular

Comment: @DainisAbols i am not using static html. This is just to try the things out.

Comment: @Irfan APIs i can create. But routing is the main issue that is going wrong. If i can not control routing of laravel from angular then i dont see any use if using angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put this files inside the public directory. As you can see in https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/structure#the-public-directory

Comment: Can i control menu in angular but get it from laravel?

Comment: Do you want to get your's html static files from Laravel, rigth? So you can create a "views" folder inside the public directory and place your's html files inside.